# Has anyone got new doc of Microsoft Power Apps?

Tags: documentation, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I'm searching for a new documentation / guide of Microsoft Power apps because some function won't work and I had a lot of error using old syntax..so Can someone has got any Guide of Power apps 2023.
Thanks Very much

I tried functions and Patches using old synthax but It won't work.
I need a 2023 guide for Power Apps

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for how to ask a good question that has more chances to be answered. In your case, can you edit your question to show what you are trying to accomplish, what expression you are currently using and what error you are getting?

Comment: Hello @carlosfigueira I'm using some functions from Doc of Microsoft and Youtube Videos to learn power apps but i have errors for example: Clearcollect is giving error on my table from sharepoint.

Comment: Please take a look at the "How to ask" link. You should be more specific, giving examples of what you tried, what error you get. Without that information it will be hard for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the official Microsoft "Learn" page for Power Apps - for ClearCollect:

[Collect, Clear, and ClearCollect functions in Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-clear-collect-clearcollect)

Answer (score 0):

This link always has the latest version of PowerApps - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/